# saving user input to a postgis table strategy

Tags: openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I have openlayers, geoserver and postgis/postgres working quite nicely.  I'm trying to create an app that allows a user to add a point to a map.  After the point is created, I need a popup form to show with various controls that allows the user to input info about the location the point has been added to.

With postgis, do I create a seperate table to hold the user input based on the p key of the added point?  Seems like a good idea to me, but I noticed the featureadded event of openlayers is triggered before the point is added to the database. Can I use geoserver to handle saving the user input, or do I need to create my own module to handle user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'featureadded' event in OpenLayers is totally client-side that occurs when you add feature to a vector layer. It has no idea whether you save feature to the database or not.

Why don't you do it like this:

1. User adds point to a map.
2. On 'featureadded' event you show a popup with input fields and 'Save' button
3. When user clicks 'Save' you save both point and input data using OpenLayers.Strategy.Save() via WFS-T

Comment: thanks @igorti that sounds like a good idea.  Doing it that way though would all the user input need to be saved in the geometry table.  I was hoping to separate it.

Comment: why do you want to store geometry and attributes in separate tables?

Comment: No specific reason i guess just would like to seperate the geometry data from the attribute data.  If it cant be done its not a major issue really

Comment: Ok, then you have two options - 1.(easiest) Store both geometries and attribute data in same table and edit them through WFS-T  2.Use WFS-T to save geometries through WFS-T and attribute data through your own webservice.

Comment: think ill opt for the easiest option at the mo as im still getting me head around this.  thanks for the help

Comment: well, to me it seems not only the easiest but a better one as well. good luck!